# How to use react component in simple html page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I want a boilerplate where I can generate a library file.

Currently I am using `create-react-app` to develop my component.

Now I want to use that component in a simple HTML page by adding a build script into the head tag.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just render your component in html

```js
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('my-app'));
```

```html
<div id='my-app'></div>
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry i want that my-app to be dynamic and can be called from any html. Before that i want to bundle MyApp using webpack that supports css loaders etc.